# updating macro results using button excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've a spreadsheet that uses a macro (user defined function) to evaluate a cell content.

Parallel to that, the background color of the same cells changes based on interaction with another spreadsheet.

However, once the cell background color changes, I need the cell content to be re-evaluated, but I can't find a way to do it.

I'm guessing I could use a button to re-evaluate all the cells every time I want to do it, but I don´t know how to do that.

What I want to avoid is to manually select every cell whose background color change and press enter so it re-evaluates the content.

Comment: Look for `Worksheet_Change` event, that might be a good start, and you also have the `.Calculate` that works on ranges and sheets!

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-calculate your workbook. This is what I suggest:

1) Open up your Macro Code (View->Macros->View Macros->Edit)

2) At the end of your Macro Add 'Application.Calculate'.  Your code will look something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    '
    'All Your Code that was there before
    '

    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

3) Click Save, and Test it out!